# Updating to Meridian Android SDK v6.6.0 causes Conscrypt-related fatal error

Tags: android

After updating my Android application to the latest current version of the Meridian SDK (6.6.0), I am now encountering the following error:

```
2020-12-12 21:42:30.000 19276-19276/lp.ex E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: lp.ex, PID: 19276
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/conscrypt/Conscrypt;
        at com.arubanetworks.meridian.Meridian.configure(Unknown Source:22)
        at com.company.myapp.App.onCreate(App.java:56)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6712)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.conscrypt.Conscrypt" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~9FzgOFIC8kjSIBvNPhj_dQ==/lp.ex-Z4Pgmnt0NrCdo9x4Ml9fyQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~9FzgOFIC8kjSIBvNPhj_dQ==/lp.ex-Z4Pgmnt0NrCdo9x4Ml9fyQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~9FzgOFIC8kjSIBvNPhj_dQ==/lp.ex-Z4Pgmnt0NrCdo9x4Ml9fyQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.arubanetworks.meridian.Meridian.configure(Unknown Source:22) 
        at com.company.myapp.App.onCreate(App.java:56) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6712) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the latest version of the Meridian SDK now requires the Conscrypt dependency. This requirement is not yet mentioned in the [official Android guide](https://docs.meridianapps.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039670134-The-Android-SDK-Guide), but the official sample code contains this new line:

```
implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.4.0' // new for Android 11
```

Adding this line to my build.gradle file fixed the error.